# Select Parent and Children in Single Column

Tags: sql, select, db2

I currently have this output:

```
ID     Name             Seq
---    -----            ----
82     Morris, Allan    1
82     Morris, Allan    2
82     Morris, Allan    3
82     Morris, Cynthia  1
82     Morris, Shaun    2
82     Morris, Sarah    3
```

But this is the desired output:

```
ID     Name             Seq
---    -----            ----
82     Morris, Allan    0
82     Morris, Cynthia  1
82     Morris, Shaun    2
82     Morris, Sarah    3
```

Here is my current query:

```
SELECT C.ID AS ID, C.Name AS Name, COALESCE(D.Seq, 0) AS Seq
FROM CMSTR C
LEFT JOIN DMSTR D ON D.ID = C.ID
UNION
SELECT C.ID AS ID, D.Name AS Name, COALESCE(D.Seq, 0) AS Seq
FROM CMSTR C
LEFT JOIN DMSTR D ON D.ID = C.ID
```

And here are the table structures:

**CMSTR**

```
ID     Name
---    -----
82     Morris, Allan
```

**DMSTR**

```
ID     Name             Seq
---    -----            ----
82     Morris, Cynthia  1
82     Morris, Shaun    2
82     Morris, Sarah    3
```

This seems like it should be a very simple query but I can't figure out how to achieve the desired output. Help please!

****EDIT****

I initially tried using the following query:

```
SELECT C.ID, (CASE WHEN D.Seq = 0 OR D.Seq IS NULL
                   THEN C.Name
                   ELSE C.Name
              END) AS Name,
       COALESCE(D.Seq, 0) AS Seq
FROM CMSTR C
LEFT JOIN DMSTR D ON D.ID = C.ID
```

Unfortunately using the above only returned the dependent names, completely excluding the parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your structure correctly (CMSTR only has 1 entry for each ID and DMSTR's Seq always starts at 1 for a given ID), this should work:

```
SELECT ID, Name, 0 AS Seq FROM CMSTR
UNION
SELECT ID, Name, Seq FROM DMSTR
-- ORDER BY ID, Seq - if you want
```

Comment: I meant to post my answer but this is the solution I ended up using. Thanks @Dukeling!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly (and I really don't know if I did), this query should give you what you want:

```
SELECT  C.ID AS ID, 
        C.Name AS Name, 
        COALESCE(D.Seq-1, 0) AS Seq
FROM CMSTR C
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ID, MIN(Seq) Seq
            FROM DMSTR
            GROUP BY ID) D 
    ON D.ID = C.ID
UNION
SELECT  ID, 
        Name, 
        Seq
FROM DMSTR
```

Comment: Thanks for your response Lamak. When I run the sub-select on its own, it works as expected but when I execute the whole query, I'm getting an error stating that the column ID doesn't exist in table D. You should also note that my actual query contains other table joins, filtering criteria and a group by that I didn't include in my OP for the sake of simplicity.

Comment: @8thWonder Weird, are you sure that you are using the query as is in my answer?, since the derived table `D` clearly has a column `ID`

Comment: those were my initial thoughts as well but I think the reason I'm getting that error is because the parent record where seq=0 doesn't actually exist in the dependent table nor does it have a seq #.